# How to mv files one by one?

Tags: command-line, files, mv

When `mv` is used between different storages, it first copies all files and then unlinks the source. 
How to `mv` files one by one, so that each file is unlinked after being copied, and the folder structure is preserved?

Comment: What do you mean one by one? If you run `mv file* target/`, that will already move each file one by one. Can you give a specific example with an example directory/file structure so we can understand what you need?

Comment: I need to move files from one FUSE mount to another, but both are located on the same physical drive that has no space for a full temporary copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `rsync` for this.

```
rsync -r --remove-source-files source_dir dest_dir
```

Files are immediately removed once transferred. Depending on which other information you need to preserve, you might actually prefer `--archive` (`-a`) over simple recursiveness (`-r`).